# MPI malloc vs MPI_Alloc_mem when to use?

Tags: c, mpi, dynamic-memory-allocation

When writing MPI programs, I've been using malloc to allocate dynamic memory, for example:

```c
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        int arr_size = 10;
        int* arr = malloc( sizeof(int) * arr_size );

        // do some MPI stuff

        MPI_Finalize();

    }
```

However, I came across this MPI function: `MPI_Alloc_mem` here:
https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Alloc_mem.html
But I'm not sure what that is for.  When should one use malloc and when should one use `MPI_Alloc_mem`?
After reading this: http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Alloc_mem.html
it seems that MPI_Alloc_mem is used mainly for remote memory access.  Why not just use malloc instead?  I couldn't find any answers that says when to choose `MPI_Alloc_mem` over `malloc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RMA **might** be faster when using memory returned by `MPI_Alloc_mem()` compared to `malloc()`. Also, `MPI_Alloc_mem()` takes an `MPI_Info` parameter you can use to optimize the memory location (note the value of this parameter is implementation specific and not covered by the standard, `MPI_INFO_NULL` will always work).

Also, some MPI implementations might choose to have `MPI_Alloc_mem()` return memory aligned on a cache line, and hence can potentially lead to better performances.

Long story short, it will not hurt using `MPI_Alloc_mem()` if the memory will be used in RMA operations. But this is really an optimization thing, and your app should work regardless how you allocate the memory (minus some restrictions, see below)

From MPI 3.1, chapter 8.2

> In some systems, message-passing and remote-memory-access (RMA)
>   operations run faster when accessing specially allocated memory (e.g.,
>   memory that is shared by the other processes in the communicating
>   group on an SMP). MPI provides a mechanism for allocating and freeing
>   such special memory. The use of such memory for message-passing or RMA
>   is not mandatory, and this memory can be used without restrictions as
>   any other dynamically allocated memory. However, implementations may
>   restrict the use of some RMA functionality as dened in Section
>   11.5.3.